# MySQL Average of timestamps and now in seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC(TOTAL_TIME_START)) AS OrderAverage
FROM Orders
WHERE `TOTAL_TIME_STOP` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I am using the above query to attempt to give me the average time that orders have been waiting in the database. TOTAL_TIME_START would be a MySQL TimeStamp field (a time in the past). But I am getting the value in seconds equivalent to 18671 days, 3 hours, 30 minutes, which is completely wrong.  Where am I going wrong??

Comment: `select 18671/365.25` will return approximately 51, and '1970-01-01' is that many years ago....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `TIME_TO_SEC()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` are doing two different things.  One is calculating the seconds for the *time* component of your `datetime`.  The other is calculating the number of seconds since `'1970-01-01'`.

One solution is simply to use `TO_SECONDS()`:

```
SELECT AVG(TO_SECONDS(NOW()) - TO_SECONDS(TOTAL_TIME_START)) AS OrderAverage
FROM Orders
WHERE `TOTAL_TIME_STOP` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This is working but I get 178787.1930 as a returned value, which converted is over 2 days, the actual average is about 14 hours.

Comment: @user1724365 . . . I cannot speak to that.  I'm not sure how you are determining the "actual" average.  This at least is comparing comparable seconds to comparable seconds.  Perhaps the issue is `NOW()` -- and your database is bit out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

As you get current time in epoch, you need to convert `TOTAL_TIME_START` to unixtimestamp too :

```
SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TOTAL_TIME_START)) AS OrderAverage
FROM Orders
WHERE `TOTAL_TIME_STOP` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```